# CSS right sidebar 100% height wont work

Tags: html, css

I have one question about 100% height. I have created this [demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/OyewKW) from codepen.io

In this demo you can see the right side have a sidebar. I am having a problem in red div on there. 100% height does not work correctly there is overflow problem. If you scoll down from red div it is scrolling but there are not have any text or something else. Anyone can tell me what i am missing on there to use without overflow.

CSS

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebarwrap {

  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 1px -1px #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 255px;
    z-index: 300;
    padding-top: 57px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 57px !important;
    min-height: 185px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width:100%;
}
.sidebarin1 {
  float: left;
    width: 255px;
    background-color: #E6E3E3;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebarin2 {
  float: left;
    width: 255px;
    background-color: #E6E3E3;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebarin3 {
      width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #E6E3E3;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
  background-color:red;
}
.sidebarin3in {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="sidebarwrap">
  <div class="col">
  <div class="sidebarin1">fdsafadsfasd fasd fa</div>
  <div class="sidebarin2">fdsafasdfasdf</div>
  <div class="sidebarin3">
    <div class="sidebarin3in"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post jsfiddle example :)

Comment: @DejanMunjiza there is an example from codepen.io

Comment: @Leothelion i want scroll bar for .sidebarin3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your sidebar a height of:

```
.sidebarin3 {    
    height: calc(100% - 66px);
}
```

where the 66px is the height of the elements above the red menu.

To make it cleaner and not "guessing" this height I would recomend to give fixed height values to these elements (in px)

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVBejJ)**

Comment: If you just check the codepen you can see the op already added overflow auto to the menu, so just add any content higher than the container and you will have the scroll bar. Damn how I hate the downvote fast triggered people. Downvoting an answer means "THIS ANSWER IS NOT USEFULL".

Comment: Nope. I didn't mean you did. usually these people that downvote so fast don't bother to even comment why. sorry if it looked I meant you. should have make 2 comments insteed of one.